# pyspark add data to a TempTable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a temporary table from a DataFrame

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(146,000000)],['id','size'])
df1.registerTempTable("table_test")
```

Now I want to add a new dataframe to the existing tempTable.

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(147,000001)],['id','size'])
```

I tried to do the following

```
df2.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("table_test")
```

But then realized that one can do that only for persistent tables.

Is it possible to add new data to an existing tempTable. If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

```
 df3=df1.union(df2) 
 df3.registerTempTable("table_test")
 hc.sql("select * from table_test").show()

+---+----+
| id|size|
+---+----+
|146|   0|
|147|   1|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  just union two dataframes and re-register temp table

```
df1.union(df2).registerTempTable("table_test")
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'union'. The solution you suggested resulted in that error. df1.unionAll(df2).registerTempTable("table_test") worked for me. Thanks though.

Comment: was the error you received `SyntaxError: invalid token` ? That was because  your data format `(147,000001)` not because my solution above.

Comment: No.. I got the error that I mentioned in my previous comment. I got the solution from your suggestion. So thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

union for spark 2 or higher, unionAll for 1.x. With same sets of cols.